# How do I partition my 500GB disk for storage?

Tags: partitioning

I have a **500GB disk**. I used 100GB for the root partition and now I would like to use the rest of the unallocated storage.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

I think your easiest option is -

1. I believe you have already installed Ubuntu in 100GB of your hard drive. That should leave 400GB unallocated space on your drive.
2. Boot into Ubuntu. Open the Disks utility (find it by clicking on the grid at the bottom left and typing Disks in to the box at the top). Identify your hard disk. You should see a + sign at the bottom when you've highlighted your drive. You can use this to 'Create partition in unallocated space'. Do that selecting 200GB of the 400GB left - and then repeat to create the third partition you want.

(3) Obviously - if you have more than one drive in your computer or any USB drives attached, be very careful you have selected the correct drive.

This will give you the three partitions you seem to be after. Linux doesn't treat drives the same way as Windows, but this will emulate a lot of the things you're used to - it will then appear as though you have 3 drives in your computer for most purposes.

Answer (score 0):

`$ sudo fdisk /dev/sda`

1.) Press `F` - this will show you whether you have unpartitioned space.

If you have 400G as you say please continue.

2.) Press `n` in order to create a new partition. (You have one disk, you need 3 partitions thus all of your partitions can be primary.)

3.) Read the text, choose the correct value and press the button.

4.) When the utility ask about size of the partition type: `200G` and press `Enter`

5.) Repeat steps above to get one more partition. Read again the questions carefully and act accordingly.

6.) If you're done with partitioning do not forget to write out the changes by pressing   `w`.

You have now two more identical linux partitions. You need to create filesystem on them.

7.) `mkfs.ext /dev/sda2 & mkfs.ext /dev/sda3`